# 'Questions' object has no attribute 'choice_set'

Tags: python, django

I've been following the Django documentation "Write your app tutorial" and I keep running into the above error. It seems to be coming from this line

```
selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
```

This is my Questions and Choices object:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date Published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choices(models.Model):
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

The code is exactly as it is on the official documentation, so I can't tell exactly where the error is coming from

Comment: You also need to have a Choice model which has Question as the foreign key.

Comment: The code is *not* exactly as the docs. Your models are callef Questions and Choices rather than Question and Choice. Things like this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"choice_set" is created as an object in Questions because the Choice model has a foreignKey relationship to Questions, so for every entry in Questions, there might be some Choice instances (rows of data in the Choice table). The general rule is a lowercase version of the model name, followed by "_set".

Your model is called Choices plural (with an 's'), so the set will probably be called "choice**s**_set". I'm pretty sure that's the remaining problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Choice model with a foreign key to Questions, otherwise django won't create choice_set.

Answer (score 0):

Your Class name is Choices, so if you try choices_set things might work